# Count and add Dynamic ID and for values for form elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a list which has some form elements like html checkbox or radio-buttons. I want to give them dynamic `ID` and `for` values to its corresponding `LABEL` tag. All this but using JQuery/JavaScript.

I am not that good in JavaScript

[image: dynamic ID and FOR values using Jquery/Javascript]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function {
    var count = 0;
    var total = $('.product-menu li').length();

  }
});
```

```css
.product-menu {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.product-menu li {
  display: list-item;
  line-height: 2;
}
.product-menu label {
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="product-menu">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="pm-1">
    <label for="pm-1">New Arrivals</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="pm-2">
    <label for="pm-2">Accessories</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="pm-3">
    <label for="pm-3">Bags</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="pm-4">
    <label for="pm-4">Jackets</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How are you creating/generating list?
If it's dynamically, why not implementing it on back-end? Or is it hard coded?

Comment: It is hard-coded ! Actually, i'm learning Javascript. So needed to know, how to do it using JavaScript/JQuery

Comment: If you're still learning, I strongly advise you to learn pure JS, and than start with jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".product-menu li").each(function(index){
        var id=$(this).find("input").attr("id");
        if(id== undefined)
        {
          $(this).find("input").prop("id","pm-"+index);
          $(this).find("label").prop("for","pm-"+index);
        }
        else
        {
          $(this).find("label").prop("for",id);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.product-menu {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.product-menu li {
    display: list-item;
    line-height: 2;
}
.product-menu label {
    font-weight: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="product-menu">
    <li>
        <input id="test" type="checkbox" >
        <label >New Arrivals</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <label >Accessories</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <label>Bags</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input id="test2" type="checkbox">
        <label >Jackets</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Maybe you should check if input ID already exists, before adding? Also, if there are IDs that already exists, than you should not use same IDs on new elements.

Comment: I would use this selector `$(".product-menu li input[id]")` to find the list of existing IDs and put them in array. Than I would use `$(".product-menu li input:not([id])")` to loop and assign new IDs, which are not in previous array.

Comment: @skobaljic thanks for that comment! I do have multiple lists, so there would have been a probability of IDs getting repeated

Answer (score 1):

Below code will add dynamic into input and for into label in each li.
Here `index` starts with 0 in each.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
      $(".product-menu li").each(function(index){
         $(this).find("input").attr("id","pm-"+index);
        $(this).find("label").attr("for","pm-"+index);  
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("product-menu")[0].children;
var listLen = list.length;

for( var i = 0; i<=listLen; i++) {
    list[i].firstElementChild.id = "pm-"+(i+1);
    list[i].lastElementChild.setAttribute("for", "pm-"+(i+1));
}
```

Comment: I left var i = 1 instead of var i = 0. Edited.